# principal component in r (interpretation) with prcomp

Tags: r, pca, interpretation

I have to analyze four portfolio of returns with a principal component analysis. I use the `prcomp` function in R.

I get the following results:
`portf. PC1   PC2
   1   0.30  -0.25
   2   0.33  -0.12
   3   0.32   0.12
   4   0.36   0.48`
When I am right, then the values in the table are my loadings. But what is the right interpretation? Can I say "the first portfolio has a correlation of 0.30 with the first principal component?
 
Thanks for help.

Comment: This isn't a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. You seem to be asking about the interpretation of results from a statistical model. If you have questions about statistical models, you should be asking at [stats.se], not here. Nothing about this seems particular to R or any programming language.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry for the wrong post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Principal components are linear combinations of your original variables.

The first principal component's score here is constructed by summing 0.3*the first portfolio returns + 0.33* the second portfolio's returns +0.32*the third's + 0.36* the fourth's.

Comment: Okay thanks, but how can I interprete the 0.30? is it like the beta in a regression?

Comment: If you're asking why is the 0.30 0.30 and not some other value, then that's because those are the loadings that maximize the variance of the first component.